# Comparing Growth rates

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

Compare the growth rates of two functions
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(n) & = n |\sin \pi n/2| + 1 \\
g(n) & = \sqrt{n}
\end{aligned}
$$

I found this stack exchange post
[Growth rate of $n^{\sin n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722356/growth-rate-of-n-sin-n?newreg=f95eeff019cb43cf81134923abd35289)

And I think this is not comparable as
$1 \leq f(n) \leq \infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

I am wondering if my thought is correct.

Comment: Think about what happens when $n=2k,k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Then $f(n) = 0$ for every $n=2k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about asymptotic comparisons, then they are not comparable. Notice that $|\sin(\pi n/2)|=0$ when $n$ is even, and $|\sin(\pi n/2)|=1$ when $n$ is odd.
So $f(n)/g(n)$ oscillates between $0$ (take limit when $n$ is even) and $+\infty$ (take limit when $n$ is odd). More precisely, $\liminf_{n\to\infty}(f(n)/g(n))=0$ and $\limsup_{n\to\infty}(f(n)/g(n))=+\infty$. The situation is the same for $g(n)/f(n)$.

Comment: thank you for clarification @bjorn93